# How to Show data from 10 tables in a single grid view according to date time descending sort

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dataset, sqldataadapter

- I Have 10 tables in total and containing same column in each `table`,
- Now i want to show the data from all the 10 tables at once in a
  single `gridview` according to `datetime` descending sort. And I want
  to execute the above query use `dataset`.
- I still found out a way to fix this using `dataview` and `datatable`.
  But this trick fails in sorting bulk data.
- Is there any other alternative to fix this?

here is my code..

```
ds2.Clear();
SqlDataAdapter getnewsfeeds;
SqlDataAdapter friendadapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from " + Session["username"].ToString() + "_friends ", friendscon);
friendadapter.Fill(friendsdataset);
int friendrowcount = friendsdataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
if (friendrowcount > 0)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < friendrowcount; i++)
    {
        friendstringtable = " " + friendsdataset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["friendsusername"].ToString();
        getnewsfeeds = new SqlDataAdapter("select top 5 * from " + friendstringtable + "_newsfeeds order by id desc", Newsfeedscon);
        getnewsfeeds.Fill(ds2, "newsfeed");
    }

}
getnewsfeeds.Fill(ds2, "newsfeed");
ds2.Tables["newsfeed"].DefaultView.Sort = "time_date desc";
DataView dv = ds2.Tables["newsfeed"].DefaultView;
dt = dv.ToTable();
```

Comment: Yes you can. Redesign database. Database table by user name? Not good.

Comment: Yes, don't create tables for every user, instead use foreign-keys to the user table. _"But this trick fails in sorting bulk data"_ In what way does it fail?

Comment: I am working on a social networking project just like facebook. And My query is i want to sort news feed of every user  according to date time descending sort. So i can not stuff all the user into a single table. Hope you understand now

Comment: @user2772216: no, you _can_ sort the table by columns of a different table if you link those tables via foreign-keys. You can also filter or group the table by user if you want.

Comment: I have a database which has limit of 200mb, I cannot have primary table which would contain the date for 10000 users and each user will have 100 posts in a day. If this happens the my database will crash.

Comment: So you have 10000 tables for users and 10000 tables for each user feeds? You think 20000 tables will take less size than 2 tables?

Comment: Also how you going to fit 10000 * 100 * day records in 200mb database? If your user and every post record took 1 *byte* and we would not count the size of empty database etc. your 200mb DB will be full after...200days.

Comment: I have same table for user and it's feed. And Each user has a unique table

Comment: Still why? You need Users, Feeds tables. Feeds will have FK to Users table. That's it all problems gone. Fetch all data from Feeds table, sort it and you have bulk sorted data. P.s. show all feeds is also not good idea.